# Getting a socket status through C++ application(Linux)

Tags: c++, sockets, netstat

I need to write a code that forcibly closes child processes that have connections in
**CLOSE_WAIT** status. It should be running at the father process and constantly
check the forked child processes(servers). Currently I cannot change the communication code at the child level. This code should be written in c++ and work on Unix/Linux.

My question is:

1. Is it a good idea to use netstat  through code and parse the result to learn
   which socket+pid is in a CLOSE_WAIT situation?
2. Is there any C++ code that enables me to easily get socket status,
   given the file descriptor number?
3. If you have any other ideas/recommendations please share.

Thanks a lot,
Ofira.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is it a good idea to use netstat through code and parse the result to learn which socket+pid is in a CLOSE_WAIT situation?

In case you are working on Linux, you should do as ss(8) does to determine the socket state.